# Unitary map in hilbert spaces, is anti isometric.

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces

If T is an anti-unitary map, prove that for all $\varphi$, $\psi\in H$, $<T\varphi,T\psi> =<\psi,\varphi>$
  (Hint: Polarization.)

I have this:

$<T\varphi,T\psi>=\frac{1}{4}(|T\varphi+T\psi|^2-|T\varphi-T\psi|^2+i|T\varphi-iT\psi|^2-i|T\varphi+iT\psi|^2)
=\frac{1}{4}(|T(\varphi+\psi)|^2-|T(\varphi-\psi)|^2+i|T(\varphi-\overline{i}\psi)|^2-i|T(\varphi+\overline{i}\psi)|^2)
=\frac{1}{4}(|\varphi+\psi|^2-|\varphi-\psi|^2+i|\varphi+i\psi|^2-i|\varphi-i\psi|^2)$

but it is not, $<\psi,\varphi>$...

pd: 
I have already been able to do it.
I just had to notice that $<\psi,\varphi>=\overline{<\varphi,\psi>}$

Thank you.

Comment: Could you define "anti-unitary" for us? The Wikipedia definition makes this trivial.

Comment: T unitary map if T(x+y)=Tx+Ty
T(lambda x)=\overline{\lambda}Tx
|Tx|=|x|

Comment: Sorry, after a quick wiki I see that the polarization depends on how you define your inner product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}\cdots &= \frac{1}{4}(|\varphi+\psi|^2-|(-1)(-\varphi+\psi)|^2+i|i(-i\varphi+\psi)|^2-i|(-i)(i\varphi+\psi)|^2)\\
&=\frac{1}{4}(|\psi+\varphi|^2-|\psi-\varphi|^2+i|\psi-i\varphi|^2-i|\psi+i\varphi)|^2)\\
&=\langle\psi,\varphi\rangle.
\end{align*}